# Send email depend group of customer, when order is pendding

Tags: magento-1.9

i have 6 groups in my store , but i want to send email when a customer makes  order, but this email need to be sending specific email, 
example, if customer is in group 3 i want to send to admingroup3@mystore.com, the email order need to be sending to admin email depend of group!!!

And i have another problem, que email orders are sending to my personal email like cc, and i cant find into system configuration, my email, i dont know if this is a problem with the datebase or something like that!!!

Comment: For your requirement, you need to customize the Magento default function. You can do this via custom extension.
For another problem, please check in System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails -> Order section.